# rolling partition schema that creates a new day and removes and 31st day on the UTC rotation

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, database-trigger

I have 200 million records in user_logs table. I followed the strategy to purge data older than 1 month.

Created a trigger function to purge data older than 1 month:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_old_user_logs()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM user_logs WHERE timestamp < now() - interval '1 month';
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

Finally, I set the trigger to be called every time a new record is inserted which deletes any records older than 1 month:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_old_user_logs
    AFTER INSERT ON user_logs
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_old_user_logs();
```

Wonderful?

However, this isn't a best way. Experts told to use partitioning instead.

So I tried to create partitioning as per the below statement-

```
create rolling partition schema that creates a new day and removes and 31st
day on the UTC rotation
```

Code Snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE purged_user_logs(
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_logs PRIMARY KEY(user_logs_id),
    CONSTRAINT ck_user_logs CHECK(timestamp > now() - interval '1 month')
) INHERITS(user_logs);
CREATE INDEX idx_user_logs ON purged_user_logs(timestamp);
```

Here is INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO purged_user_logs(user_logs_id, timestamp)
SELECT user_logs_id, timestamp
from user_logs where timestamp > now() - interval '1 month';
```

Here is function:

```
create or replace function on_purged_user_insert() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if (new.timestamp > now() - interval '1 month') then
        insert into purged_user_logs values (new.*);     
    else
        raise exception 'timestamp date out of range';
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Here is trigger:

```
create trigger user_logs_insert
before insert on user_logs
for each row execute procedure on_purged_user_insert();
```

Is that correct as per the statement ? 
No, Removal is missing. So we need another trigger for removal?

INSERT Trigger is correct or not?

Comment: You could use your old trigger for removal, just add `returning *` and then insert from that data into "archive" partition in the same fashion you do with fresh data. I'm not sure if this rolling partition will work well with your huge data tho. This is gonna triple number of queries that are done for each insert and it will query your huge table on hopefully indexed column, but still...

Comment: I think you might get better responses if you ask how to solve specific problem instead of how to implement chosen solution.

Comment: I would not use a trigger to do this job at all. That will make the insert command slow. Instead I would create a job and schedule it to run once a day. You can do so either with pgagent or pg_cron or even an external cron that calls a statement